# Clustering high dimension data set

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset of 90000 rows and 200 columns. I trying to form clusters. I have reduced the size using pca. When try it in python I get MemoryError. I understand the problem is because of the no of rows. How can i cluster this dataset

I tried different dimensionality reduction algorithms like pca tsne kernal pca.

Comment: All of the the dim reduction algorithms give you memory error? If so you need to provision more memory to your environment (memory collection, buffed cloud instance, cast your data to lower precision).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.